# What is the best way to use if([names count]>1) in swift?

Tags: ios, swift

In Objective C we used

```
 if([names count]>1){
   // array count is greater than one
}
```

The same way i tried to check in swift. But the complier shouts.

Any idea??

Comment: Show the swift code and the compiler message

Comment: What error message does the compiler emit?

Comment: Why is this tagged Objective-C?

Comment: This isn't even correct Objective-C syntax

Comment: First of all post your Swift code. Is `names` an  `Array` or a `String`? Is the type optional?

Comment: @sbooth, i tagged Obj C, because am comparing ObjC and Swift.

Comment: @MatthiasBauch perhaps you could elaborate on why this is not correct Objective-C syntax? Otherwise the comment is not really helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is incorrect.  Brackets are used in Objective-C, not Swift.

Try this:

```
var shoppingList = ["Eggs", "Milk"]
if(1 < shoppingList.count) {
    println( "Greater than one")
}
```

Comment: That's why the question says "in Objective C we used..."

Comment: Yoda conditionals are not very readable and offer no benefit in Swift.

Comment: @Zaph Readability is subjective but you're right that there is no benefit as far as inadvertent assignment is concerned.

Comment: Shouldn't that start: "Subjective is readability" ;-)

Answer (score 4):

The correct way to write it should be:

```
if name.count > 1 {
    // Your code here
}
```

Comment: My god, thanks @Jean-Philippe I was on my mobile phone when I answered!